# Function doesn't work even if it returns true

Tags: php, function

I'm creating an online Blood Donation Management website. On the Staff user side of the website, there's a "Mark as Done" function for when a Blood Donor has successfully attended and completed a scheduled Blood Donation Appointment.

Once, the staff user clicks "Mark as Done" the following is supposed to happen:

1. The 'completed' column of the appointment in tblappointments is updated to `1`
2. The Donor user gets notified that their appointment has been marked completed by the Staff user.
3. The value of 'bloodUnitsReceived' column increases by 1. (Eg: If patient has received 2 blood units so far, a new Donation will update `bloodUnitsReceived` column into 3)
4. The "Acquirer", i.e., the user related to the patient, who is asking for blood donations on their behalf, gets notified that someone has donated blood to them.

Everything above works successfully. Now, after notifying the donor and acquirer, I want the system to check whether the patient has received all the bloodunits they need (i.e `if(amtBloodUnitsNeeded == bloodUnitsReceived)`). If so, the acquirer gets notified that their patient/loved one has completed their prescribed blood units and their blood donation request gets archived.

This is the function that I made:

```
function checkAndMarkPatientDone($conn,$patientID){
        //check if patient has completed donations needed
        $checkReceived = $conn->query("Select acquirerID,patientFN, patientMI, patientLN, amtBloodUnits, bloodUnitsReceived from tblpatient where id = '$patientID'");

        if($checkReceived -> num_rows>0){    

          $bloodUnits= $checkReceived->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC); 
          foreach($bloodUnits as $blood){
            
            $amtBloodUnits = $blood['amtBloodUnits'];
            $bloodReceived = $blood['bloodUnitsReceived'];
            $patientFullName = $blood['patientFN']." ".$blood['patientMI'].". ".$blood['patientLN'];
            $acquirerID = $blood['acquirerID'];
            
          }

          //if blood units received have matched blood units needed
          if($bloodReceived == $amtBloodUnits){
            //update patient as complete
            $update = "UPDATE tblpatient set completed = 1 where id = '$patientID'";

            //archive blooddonation request
            $archiveRequest = "UPDATE blooddonationrequest as r INNER JOIN tblpatient as p on r.patientID = p.id set archived = 1 where p.id = '$patientID'";

            if(($conn->query($update)==TRUE) && ($conn->query($archiveRequest)==TRUE)) {
                return true;
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }
          }
          else{
            return false;
          }
        }
    }
```

This is where I call the function, and send notifications and email notifications when the function returns true:

```
if(checkAndMarkPatientDone($conn,$patientID)==true){
          //notify acquirer
                 $icon = "/WBBSD/header/done.png";
                $notifTitle = "Your goal of reaching".$unitsNeeded." blood units for ".$patientName." has been reached!";
                $notifMsg = "It\'s our pleasure in helping you find the blood your loved one needs. We pray for your loved one\'s healing!";
                $usertype = "acquirer";
                $acquirerID = $acquirerID;

                if(addNotif($conn,$icon, $notifTitle, $notifMsg,$usertype,$acquirerID)==false){
                   $_SESSION['errorMsg'] = "Error notifying about blood completion.";
                }

                //send email to acquirer
          $acquirerDetails = getAcquirerDetails($conn,$acquirerID);
          $userEmail = $acquirerDetails['email'];
          $userFullName = $acquirerDetails['firstName']." ".$acquirerDetails['middleInitial'].". ".$acquirerDetails['lastName'];

          $emailResult = sendEmail($userEmail,$notifMsg,$userFullName,$notifTitle);

        $_SESSION['informMsg'].="\n Acquirer Email Status: ".$emailResult;
}
```

The problem that I have is that this code under `if(checkAndMarkPatientDone($conn,$patientID)==true){` doesn't run at all. All the code and functions before it complete work (complete code below), but it's as if the system just ignores this part of the code. At first I thought that maybe the `checkAndMarkPatientDone()` function wasn't returning true, So I tested the function and called it in a separate PHP file. During testing, the function did work successfully and returned true, but when I include it together with other pieces of code, it doesn't work.

Here is the complete code for when a staff clicks a "Mark as Done" Button for a blood donation appointment for your reference:

```
   if (isset($_POST['btnDone'])) {

      $requestID = $_POST['requestID'];
      //need to know donor id to know who to add
      $donorID = $_POST['donorID'];
      //update that tblappointment is done
      $updatequery = "UPDATE tblappointment SET completed = 1 where donationRequestID = '$requestID'";
      if($conn->query($updatequery)==TRUE){
        $_SESSION['successMsg'] = "Appointment successfully marked complete";

      //record donation to patient and donor side
        if(addDonation($conn,$donorID,$requestID) == TRUE){
          $_SESSION['successMsg'].=" and donation recorded successfully";

          //notify donor for completed appointment
          $icon = "/WBBSD/header/blood-donation.png";
          $notifTitle = "Your appointment was marked complete.";
          $notifMsg = "Thank you for attending and completing your blood donation. Make sure to get enough rest and nutrients. Come back after 3 months!";
          $usertype = "donor";
          $donorID = $donorID;

          if(addNotif($conn,$icon, $notifTitle, $notifMsg,$usertype,$donorID)==false){
                  $_SESSION['errorMsg'] = "Error with notifying donor.";
                }//if addnotif flase

           //send email to donor
          $donorDetails = getDonorDetails($conn,$donorID);
          $userEmail = $donorDetails['email'];
          $userFullName = $donorDetails['firstName']." ".$donorDetails['middleInitial'].". ".$donorDetails['lastName'];
            
          $_SESSION['informMsg'] ="Donor Email Status: ".sendEmail($userEmail,$notifMsg,$userFullName,$notifTitle);


          //get patient details for acquirer notification
          $patientresult = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM tblpatient as p INNER JOIN tblappointment as a on p.id = a.patientID where a.donationRequestID = '$requestID'");
          if($patientresult -> num_rows>0){

            $pDetails= $patientresult->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC); 
            foreach($pDetails as $pDetail){
              $patientName = $pDetail['patientFN']." ".$pDetail['patientMI'].". ".$pDetail['patientLN'];
              $apptDate = $pDetail['apptDate'];
              $bloodReceived = $pDetail['bloodUnitsReceived'];
              $bloodReceived = $pDetail['bloodUnitsReceived'];
              $unitsNeeded = $pDetail['amtBloodUnits'];
              $acquirerID = $pDetail['acquirerID'];
              //for checking if donations are complete
              $patientID = $pDetail['id'];
            }//foreach pdetails         
        }//if patientresult

        //notify acquirer for new donation
        $icon = "/WBBSD/header/help.png";
        $notifTitle = "Your loved one has received a blood donation!.";
        $notifMsg = "One of our registered blood donors has successfully donated blood for your loved one, ".$patientName." on ".$apptDate.". Your request has received ".$bloodReceived."/".$unitsNeeded." blood units so far.";
        $usertype = "acquirer";
        $acquirerID = $acquirerID;

        if(addNotif($conn,$icon, $notifTitle, $notifMsg,$usertype,$acquirerID)==false){
                $_SESSION['errorMsg'] = "Error with notifying donor.";
              }//if addnotif flase

        //send email to acquirer
          $acquirerDetails = getAcquirerDetails($conn,$acquirerID);
          $userEmail = $acquirerDetails['email'];
          $userFullName = $acquirerDetails['firstName']." ".$acquirerDetails['middleInitial'].". ".$acquirerDetails['lastName'];

        $_SESSION['informMsg'].="\n Acquirer Email Status: ".sendEmail($userEmail,$notifMsg,$userFullName,$notifTitle);

  

//check if reached blood goal
              if(checkAndMarkPatientDone($conn,$patientID)==true){
          //notify acquirer
                 $icon = "/WBBSD/header/done.png";
                $notifTitle = "Your goal of reaching".$unitsNeeded." blood units for ".$patientName." has been reached!";
                $notifMsg = "It\'s our pleasure in helping you find the blood your loved one needs. We pray for your loved one\'s healing!";
                $usertype = "acquirer";
                $acquirerID = $acquirerID;

                if(addNotif($conn,$icon, $notifTitle, $notifMsg,$usertype,$acquirerID)==false){
                   $_SESSION['errorMsg'] = "Error notifying about blood completion.";
                }

                //send email to acquirer
          $acquirerDetails = getAcquirerDetails($conn,$acquirerID);
          $userEmail = $acquirerDetails['email'];
          $userFullName = $acquirerDetails['firstName']." ".$acquirerDetails['middleInitial'].". ".$acquirerDetails['lastName'];

          $emailResult = sendEmail($userEmail,$notifMsg,$userFullName,$notifTitle);

        $_SESSION['informMsg'].="\n Acquirer Email Status: ".$emailResult;
         }//if check

//everything successful
        header("location: ../staff/staff_dash.php");
      }
      
      else{
        $_SESSION['errorMsg']="Failed to record donation";
      }       
    
    }
    else{
     $_SESSION['errorMsg'] = "Unable to mark appointment complete. Please try again.";
    }
   }
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Ignoring all the SQL injection issues, we have no idea what  `$conn` is, which arguably is the most important detail, is it a PDO instance?

Comment: Oh, sorry. $conn holds the connection to the database

Comment: I gathered that, but that's still not helpful. What is it, a `mysqli` object, `PDO`, an ORM handler? You need to be more precise in what information you are providing, and reduce the amount of information as a lot seems unnecessary.

Comment: It's a mysqli object

Comment: Right, first of all the query method of a `mysqli` never returns true, it's either `false` or a `mysqli_result`, so checking against `true` is a bit weird, although not the issue because of the weak comparison you are doing.

The question is are you getting "inside" this if block: `if($bloodReceived == $amtBloodUnits){`

Comment: Within the `foreach($bloodUnits as $blood)` loop, do you mean to sum up all the values for `$blood['amtBloodUnits']` and `$blood['bloodUnitsReceived']` and check them after the loop has completed? As it stands you'll only be checking the values from the final result.